# JQuery - Send inputs via ajax (which were obtained by ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, input

I have an application that after performing a search, returns me multiple "fieldsets" with some hidden inputs (via AJAX!).
I want to use these inputs to send information to the server (again) via AJAX.
The names of these inputs are automatically listed with a prefix:

"video_url_1", "video_url_2", etc.

When the user clicks the button, the value of "video_url_1" or "video_url_2" will be sent via AJAX depending on the button to which it has clicked. To solve this I got the name of the button that was clicked and then I cut the name so that I only have one number, this number I put in a variable and then use it in the "data" section of AJAX.

I did the test by sending a locally stored input and it worked but when trying to send the inputs that were previously obtained by an ajax, it does not work.
What can be wrong? This is my code:

```
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            $('a.report_video').click(function() { 
                var idbutton = $(this).attr('id');
                var idreport = idbutton.replace('report_video_', '');
                //I'm still not using these variables, can they be used to pass the input data to ajax?
                var videourl = $("#video_url_" + idreport).val();
                var videoid = $("#video_id_" + idreport).val();
                var videoserver = $("#server").val();
                ///////////

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : 'https://example.com/script/script.php',
                    data : $($("#video_url_" + idreport)).serialize(), //It doesn't work
                    //For example, data: $("#server").serialize() 
                    //Work fine, this input is stored locally. 
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#video_report_' + idreport).html('<img src="'+pluginUrl+'./assets/img/loading.svg" />');
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $('#video_report_' + idreport).html(data);
                });

                return false; 
            });     


        });
```

Edit:
I just did some tests as suggested by Kevin B and I see that the problem I have is in the syntax when trying to send two dynamic ID's by Ajax.
The problem is that I do not know how to write them correctly, I know that is the problem because when I tried to send them separately they did work...

```
data : $($("#video_id_" + idreport), $("#video_url_" + idreport)).serialize(),
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to how you are building `data` for your second ajax request. Without knowing what those elements are, we can't really help all that much. .serialize when called on a form or a collection of input elements works fine, but, we don't know what you're selecting with `$("#video_url_" + idreport)` or if it's even selecting anything.

Comment: Hello Kevin B, I've updated my question.

Comment: AT the point where you're unsure, use the debugging tools available to you to be sure. insert console.logs, add break points, etc. there's no point in being unsure when you can just test it. We unfortunately can't test it.

Comment: Hi @Kevin B, I just found the problem and it is in my syntax, you can see where it is wrong, the problem is in the "data" line, I want to send two input names composed by a prefix and a variable, when I tried to send it by separate worked but when I wanted to do it together, no.

Comment: `$("#foo, #bar").serialize()` jquery selectors work just like css selectors.

Comment: But the ID is composed of a prefix and a numeric variable where "idreport" can be "1, 2, 3". The name would be # foo_1 or # foo_2.

Comment: yeah, that's fine. simple string concatenation.

Comment: Could you give me an example ?. I am not an expert in jquery. I tryed $("#foo" + idreport, "#bar" + idreport).serialize();

Comment: `("#foo" + idreport + ",#bar" + idreport)`

Comment: Thanks for the help, they are the kind of thing that happens to an amateur in jquery.

Comment: problem is it's not even jquery, potentially not even javascript. just math

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your problem, but this might help.

You call your second `AJAX` call in the `.success()` method of the first `AJAX` call. Essentially chaining the responses.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'someURL',
        data: someData
    }).done(function(firstCallData) {
        // This OPTIONAL method fires when the AJAC call succeeded
        // You can also put another AJAX call in here with the data returned from the first call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'someURL',
            data: firstCallData
        }).done(function(data) {
            // Do something with second AJAX call with data
        }).fail(function(data) {
            // Second AJAX call failed, handle error
        });
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // This OPTIONAL method fires when the first response failed
    }).always(function(data) {
        // This OPTIONAL method fires regardless if the first call succeeded or failed.
    });
});
```

Comment: don't use .success. replace it with .done. it doesn't exist in 3.x+

Comment: @KevinB Whoops, I put `.done()` in the first call but mistakenly put `.success()` in the second call. Use `.done()`.

Comment: I also don't think this answer is related to the question. If the question is unclear, request clarification and/or close it as such.